# Disable Mouse Drag Transform in properties window

Tags: interface, properties

When clicking properties in the properties-window (or at least I think it's called that way - 'N' to open) it sometimes won't let me edit the values with my keyboard because I slightly moved my mouse while doing so.
How can I disable that?

Since I don't know how to accurately describe it in words, here is an example.

[image: This is what I want to disable]

Comment: I don't think you can disable somehow sliding event, but you can click on the slider with holding Ctrl to workaround that